# How do I get around "HttpListenerBase.Instance has already been set" in my ServiceStack-hosted tests?

Tags: servicestack, httplistener, servicestack-bsd

I've got a project build on ServiceStack 3.9, with extensive test coverage that uses ServiceStack's self-hosting API facility.

Lots of my test fixtures look like this:

```cs
private const string URL_BASE = "http://localhost:60666/";

[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void TestFixtureSetUp() {
    AppHost = new HttpTestableAppHost(FakeServices.Register);
    AppHost.Init();
    AppHost.Start(URL_BASE);
}

[TestFixtureTearDown]
public void TestFixtureTearDown() {
    AppHost.Dispose();
    AppHost = null;
}
```

The problem is that if when tests fail, the TearDown doesn't always seem to be running cleanly - and then every other test on the project fails with the same errors, either

> System.IO.InvalidDataException : HttpListenerBase.Instance has already been set

or less frequently

> Failed to listen on prefix `http://localhost:60666/` because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine

When this happens, the entire test suite becomes un-runnable for a couple of minutes - presumably whilst some underlying piece of network binding times out or gets disposed? - and then after a few minutes it all starts working again.

How can I handle this more gracefully? Is there some way I can forcibly dispose/unregister that `http://localhost:60666/` endpoint before initialising my AppHost, so it'll kill any existing service hosts before starting a fresh one? It's increasingly difficult to work out what's going on when one 'proper' failing test results in 1,000+ test failures because the other tests can't initialise their HTTP listener.

Comment: Ooh. Yes, yes we did - but it took so long to get your solution integrated into our codebase that I completely forgot where it came from - sorry!

Comment: Awesome :) Glad it was useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unload the AppDomain:

The only way to cleanly restart the ServiceStack host is to unload the application domain it is running in and start a fresh instance in a new application domain.

Your issue is [related to this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26034297/1295344).

### 1: Create your AppHost (as per normal):

An example `AppHost` which registers an object called `MyTest` with the IoC container.

```cs
public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
{
    public AppHost(): base("My ServiceStack Service", typeof(AppHost).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        container.Register<MyTest>(c => new MyTest());
    }
}

public class MyTest
{
    public string Name { get { return "Hello"; } }
}
```

### 2: Create an `IsolatedAppHost` Class:

The `IsolatedAppHost` class is used to start your application host, that will be run in the isolated AppDomain. You can start and configure whatever `AppHost` you need here, such as your `HttpTestableAppHost`.

```cs
public class IsolatedAppHost : MarshalByRefObject
{
    readonly AppHost Host;

    public IsolatedAppHost()
    {
        // Start your HttpTestableAppHost here
        Host = new AppHost();
        Host.Init();
        Host.Start("http://*:8090/");
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceStack is running in AppDomain '{0}'", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
    }

    public void RunTest(Action<AppHost> test)
    {
        test.Invoke(Host);
    }

    public void Teardown()
    {
        if(Host != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shutting down ServiceStack host");
            if(Host.HasStarted)
                Host.Stop();
            Host.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

### 3: Create your `TestFixture`:

Your `TestFixureSetup` method will need to create an instanced of the `IsolatedAppHost` in a new `AppDomain`. And the `TestFixtureTearDown` will ensure the `AppHost` and the domain are correctly shutdown.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    AppDomain ServiceStackAppDomain;
    IsolatedAppHost IsolatedAppHost;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetup()
    {
        // Get the assembly of our host
        var assemblyName = typeof(IsolatedAppHost).Assembly.GetName();

        // Create new AppDomain
        ServiceStackAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ServiceStackAppDomain");

        // Load our assembly
        ServiceStackAppDomain.Load(assemblyName);

        // Create instance
        var handle = ServiceStackAppDomain.CreateInstance(assemblyName.FullName, "MyApp.Tests.IsolatedAppHost");

        // Unwrap so we can access methods
        IsolatedAppHost = (IsolatedAppHost)handle.Unwrap();
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TestFixtureTearDown()
    {
        // Tell ServiceStack to stop the host
        IsolatedAppHost.Teardown();

        // Shutdown the ServiceStack application
        AppDomain.Unload(ServiceStackAppDomain);
        ServiceStackAppDomain = null;
    }

    // Tests go here
}
```

### 4: Running tests:

As the test runner `AppDomain` and the `AppHost` `AppDomain` are now different, we cannot access the `AppHost` from our tests directly. So we pass our test to the `RunTest` method instance of our `IsolatedAppHost`.

```cs
IsolatedAppHost.RunTest(appHost => {
    // Your test goes here
});
```

For example:

```cs
[Test]
public void TestWillPass()
{
    IsolatedAppHost.RunTest(appHost => {
        var t = appHost.TryResolve<MyTest>();
        Assert.That(t.Name, Is.EqualTo("Hello"));
    });
}

[Test]
public void TestWillFail()
{
    IsolatedAppHost.RunTest(appHost => {
        var t = appHost.TryResolve<MyTest>();
        Assert.That(t.Name, Is.EqualTo("World"));
    });
}
```

The [full source code is here](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/f7934dccf3d5ba2fd6fc). I hope that helps.